# C++ What exactly does exit() do when using multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2019, exit

I'm working on some code that uses an existing code-base which is now a DLL. What I'm trying to do it to terminate all the threads that are were started, but keep my main program running.

This is the basic structure of the code:

```
void Mainprogram()
{
   tempProcessingThreadHandle = (HMODULE)_beginthread(SomeDLLEntry, 0, (void)&Params);  //SomeDLLEntry is a function in some.dll
   //Other Code I Want to Run
}
```

In the DLL:

```
void SomeDLLEntry()
{  
   tempProcessingThreadHandle = (HMODULE)_beginthread(SomeOtherDLLThing1, 0, (void)&Params);
   tempProcessingThreadHandle = (HMODULE)_beginthread(SomeOtherDLLThing2, 0, (void)&Params);

   if (someCondition)
      return;
}

void SomeOtherDLLThing1()
{
   if (someOtherCondition)
      exit(1);
}
```

I thought that returning from `SomeDLLEntry()` would cause the threads started in the DLL (`SomeOtherDLLThing1` and `2`) to terminate as well, but that's not the case, as seen in the debugger; `SomeDLLEntry()` thread would disappear, but the others are still running.

Now, if I set `someOtherCondition` to true, and `exit(1)` is called from `SomeOtherDLLThing1()`, what should happen? When I debug over this, the debugger seems to crash, but it appears to go past the `exit(1)` line and give me:

> Unhandled exception at 0x6B4E87CD (Mso20win32client.dll) in Mainprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000018C.

Is this because the whole process (including `Mainprogram()`) has been terminated? What exactly does calling `exit(1)` in `SomeOtherDLLThing1()` do? How can I properly terminate all of the DLL-related threads and continue with my `Mainprogram()`?

Comment: You tagged this as C++, and the way threads are done in C++ is to use `std::thread` and its set of functions related to it.

Comment: `exit()` exits the process, just as the documentation states.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to safely terminate threads and continue to execute is to coordinate with those threads, have them cleanly finish, then join the thread handles.

There is no free lunch.

Other choices are "hack, force halt of threads, and pray you get lucky" or "do your work in another process, and pray summary shutdown causes no problems".

Comment: Is returning from the functions the clean way to finish them? Thus have SomeOtherDLLThing 1 and 2 return, and then finally return from SomeDLLEntry?

Comment: @PhoeniX -- Do those threads depend on each other in some way?  If so, all of the things you mentioned need to be synchronized.  Just returning does not guarantee that "SomeOtherDLLThing 1" will actually terminate the thread before "SomeOtherDLLThing 2" if you returned in the order of 1 and then 2..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No not from what I see, they don't depend on each other. I'll try to work things around to return from all the SomeOtherDLLThings first and then return from SomeDLLEntry

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and Adam So what exactly does exit(1) do in this case, with all these threads? Do they do different things if they were in a different thread/spot?

Comment: @PhoeniX exit shuts down the process.  What it does when there are active threads is underspecified by the C++ standard